# Subscribing to an interface's events in C#

Tags: c#, events, interface, delegates, event-handling

I am creating a game (in Unity). I would like the input handling to be de-coupled from the game logic so that it can go cross-platform. I have an interface named `IInputHandler` that can be implemented differently per platform. E.g.,

```
public class AndroidInputHandler : IInputHandler
```

or

```
public class PcInputHandler : IInputHandler
```

The reason I want this interface is so that I can do something like this:

```
public class PlayerController {

     private IInputHandler _inputHandler;
     private Player _myPlayer;
     // ... 
     _inputHandler.ForwardKeyPressed += _myPlayer.MoveForward();
```

As you can see, I want an interface whose methods I can subscribe to such that any time the "move forward" key is pressed, whether that be the "W" key on a PC or a tap on the screen for Android, my `Player` moves forward. I have tried using `delegates` in my `IInputHandler` interface, but delegates and interfaces don't seem to play nicely together. How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Edit: What I've tried:

```
public interface IInputHandler {

    event ForwardKeyPressed();
```

The error message: "The type or namespace `ForwardKeyPressed` cannot be found."

Comment: Could you show some actual code about the issue? You can define events in interfaces and then use them exactly as you want

Comment: Sure. Perhaps I am just unfamiliar with the syntax, but the compiler complains when I try to put the following method in my interface: `event ForwardKeyPressed()`. It says "the type or namespace `ForwardKeyPressed` could not be found".

Comment: Please edit the question with the code and exact error messages. It may very well be just a question of syntax

Comment: You are gong to need some top level code that is going to determine the platform.  In this code you button event can simply be an if statement to register the event depending on the platform.

Comment: @jdweng You are misunderstanding my question. I am wondering how to write a method in an interface that can be subscribed to.

Comment: I not sure you can since the click event are not the same for a button in an Android and a PC.  They are not inherited from the same base class.

Comment: I would create a base class with two inherited classes (one for PC and one for Android).  Then I don't think you need the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a type for the event.

As an example,

```
public interface IInputHandler 
{
    event EventHandler<ForwardKeyPressedEventArgs> ForwardKeyPressed;
}
```

Comment: Adding a type for each event seems excessive. In that case I would have to declare `LeftKeyPressedEventArgs`, `JumpKeyPressedEventArgs`, `Ability1KeyPressedEventsArgs`, etc. Is there no simpler way to do it?

Comment: @Alex You could just use an `EventHandler`. Or you could declare a class called `KeyPressedEventArgs` for any type of key press event. It's up to you.  The basic problem you had boiled down to a syntax error.